# Netlogo, Mapping one to one over two lists

Tags: netlogo

I want to find out how to map one to one from two lists. Where length of both the lists are the same.
For Example,
list A = [turtle-0 turtle-3 turtle-5]
list B = [Node-27 node-21 node-29]

I want to map,
 turtle-0 to node-27
 turtle-3 to node-21
 turtle-5 to node-29

and store each of the nodes in turtle-own variable called travel-to.
I have feeling you can achieve this the map or foreach functions, but unfortunately I haven't been successful. Any ideas, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using indices, as in geruter's answer, will work, but isn't necessary.

Both `map` and `foreach` let you process multiple lists by surrounding the whole call in parentheses, so for example:

```
observer> show (map [[?a ?b] -> word ?a ?b] [1 2 3] ["a" "b" "c"])
observer: ["1a" "2b" "3c"]
```

or, shorthand syntax,

```
observer> show (map word [1 2 3] ["a" "b" "c"])
observer: ["1a" "2b" "3c"]
```

re:

> I have feeling you can achieve this the map or foreach functions, but unfortunately I haven't been successful.

It would help us help you if you showed us your best attempt, and described where you got stuck (was there an error message? incorrect behavior?).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I am still not quite sure how to set it in turtle context. For example from my original question, for each turtle in list A to take the corresponding node from list B and a the turtle-own variable (respective-node) to that value.The code below is incorrect, but something like this : map [[i j] -> ask turtle i [set respective-node j]] list-A list-B

Comment: Seth, can you fix the `map` in my answer? OP wants to assign from one map to agents identified in the other list (I think), not just concatenate

Comment: @JenB in order to use `map`, you have to do something with the list of results, as with any reporter. if you don't care about the results, you should use `foreach` (command) instead of `map` (reporter)

Comment: Thanks Seth - that makes sense. I will update my answer.

Comment: You still don't need indices though... you can do it with a single `(foreach agents destinations [...])` (with the parens).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the pros here will come up with a better solution, but the code below should work.
Actually you could use `foreach` or `map`, both return the same results.

The 2 report functions below work for lists, not quiet sure of the also will work with agentsets.

```
to test
  let list1 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  let list2 ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"]

  show foreach-2-lists list1 list2
  show map-2-lists list1 list2
end


to-report foreach-2-lists [list1 list2]

  let result []

  if length list1 != length list2 [ report "Error" ]

  let index range length list1

  foreach index [ i ->
    set result lput ( list ( item i list1 ) ( item i list2 ) ) result
  ]

  report result


end

to-report map-2-lists [list1 list2]

  if length list1 != length list2 [ report "Error" ]

  let index range length list1

  let result map [ i -> ( list ( item i list1 ) ( item i list2 ) ) ] index

  report result

end
```

`test` will return you the result of both functions:

```
observer> test
observer: [[1 "a"] [2 "b"] [3 "c"] [4 "d"] [5 "e"] [6 "f"]]
observer: [[1 "a"] [2 "b"] [3 "c"] [4 "d"] [5 "e"] [6 "f"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

See below for a version using `foreach`. The trick is to access the two lists through parallel iteration. This won't work with `map` because you are wanting to do a command (that is, change things) rather than a reporter (extract information).

```
turtles-own [ my-destination ]

to testme
  clear-all
  ; set up test data lists
  create-turtles 5
  let agents shuffle sort-on [who] n-of 3 turtles
  print agents
  let destinations (list "A" (one-of patches) 33 )
  print destinations
  ; do the matching with foreach
  let indices range length agents
  foreach indices
  [ idx ->
    ask item idx agents
    [ set my-destination item idx destinations
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [ show my-destination ]
end
```